# Nextjs Upload Data on Database

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, next.js13, http-status-code-500

I'm facing an issue when trying to add a task to the database on My TodoApp. I'm getting an internal server error with a status code of 500. I have checked my code, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of the error.
I check model file and route file but cannot track the error.

I created this onTaskadded function. when anyone clicks on the button (add task) function call the route file to upload the task in DB. I follow the same step for my login finality it's working but when I try to add a task in my database getting an error.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

> //file location src>components>addtodo.tsx

```
 const onTaskAdded = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await axios.post("/api/usertask", values.todo);
      toast.success("task added successfully", response.data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
    };
```

> //file location api>usertask>route.ts

```
import { Connect } from "@/db/dbConfig";
import Task from "@/models/todoModel";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

Connect();

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const reqBody = await request.json();
    const { task, completed } = reqBody;

    //checking if task body is empty
    if (!task) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Task is required." }, { status: 400 });
    }

    const userTask = new Task({ task, completed });

    const savedUser = await userTask.save();
    console.log(savedUser);

    return NextResponse.json({
      message: "Task added successfully.",
      success: true,
      savedUser,
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Internal server error." },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

> DB connection file

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export async function Connect() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL!, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    } as any);

    const connection = await mongoose.connection;
    connection.on("connected", () => {
      console.log("MongoDB connected");
    });

    connection.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("MongoDB connection error" + err);
      process.exit(1);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("something goes wrong!");
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```